# express-validator: query-parameters with filter

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I have a query parameter which could be used as a filter, looking like this:

```
query1=test
or
query1[gt]=100
or
query1[gte]=101
....
```

How do I integrate this into express-validator? It should be possible to append the querystrings **parameters** with more optional filter functionallity.

Even this, which is by far the worst approche, is not working.

```
query('query1').isAlphanumeric().optional()
query('query1[gt]').isAlphanumeric().optional()
```

Is there a way to do so? I was thinking about a regex pattern, but as I know its not possible to match a regex against parameters, only against values.